# YA series about magical cats which have some kind of ability that involved seeing strings

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm looking for a series I read five or more years ago, about cats (strays, but also house cats) who I'm pretty sure lived in a fairly big city and had some kind of ability that involved seeing strings(?) or nets or tangles or something like that in the air, and 'fixing' them, or maybe using them somehow. I remember--though this might have been a different novel--a section about a ame the cats of the city played, which I believe was about finding a perch where you could see as many other cats as possible, with as few of them seeing you?

I think that at least one of the books (of which I read two, not sure if there was more) had something do to with 'moon' in the title, and I think the second one had to do with kittens and a queen?

I distinctly remember one scene where the protagonists are in a subway or train station and find the body of a young cat on the tracks, who I'm fairly certain turns out to be still alive.

Comment: Cats that *can't* see strings - *that* would require magic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first book is Diane Duane's '[The Book of Night with Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Night_with_Moon)' aka, 'The Cats of Grand Central Station', the second '[To Visit the Queen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Visit_the_Queen)' aka 'On Her Majesty's Wizardly Service.'  (The second titles represent the UK printing titles.)

They are part of / related to the '[Young Wizards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards)' series.

The kitten you mention is named 'Arhu.' The game is called 'hauissh' (literally 'The Fight') and is symbolic of a Historical / Mythical fight from pre-history.

> "...You tell me now, young tom: who do you think's holding down the most important stance at the moment?"
>
> Arhu looked around him in bemusement. "Her," he said, flirting his tail sideways to indicate the handsome chocolate-brown cat who crouched, immobile as a statue, on one of the nearby walls between two buildings.
>
> "And you wouldn't be too far off. Trust Hmahilh' to hog a good spot at the earliest opportunity. But why?"
>
> Arhu looked up and down the street. "Because she can see everybody else," he said, "and not everybody else can see her."

The cats Rhiow, Saash, Urruah (and later Arhu) maintain the Grand Central Station World-gating facility; they control it by plucking the 'control strings' of the gate.

It's an enjoyable series; it started as the YA Wizard books, but these (the Cat books) were written to venture a bit more away from the YA market, and even the base series itself has slowly grown up along with it's main characters.

[image: Book of Night with Moon]
[image: To Visit the Queen]

Comment: Yessss thank you so much! I never knew, even back then, that they were part of a larger series. My google search probably would have turned up something more than it did if I hadn't been so convinced it was a YA series...

Comment: @BonesTheHeretic - Well, it's not a bad assumption; it's a related set of books TO at YA series, these are just not YA themselves.  Makes sense in that the first of the YA books was written in 83, and the first of these in 97; her initial audience had grown up :)

Comment: There is a third book in the series, although it's never been formally published, only self-published on a website with a subscription model that never quite panned out as planned (it was projected the book would be done within a year, when in fact it took five).  All the chapters of _The_ _Big_ _Meow_ are online at [the website for the project](http://www.the-big-meow.com/Chapters-Online).